# Q: Get Item's Title Python eBay SDK

Tags: python, ebay-sdk

I am trying to get item's title with "GetSingleItem" method by providing the ItemID, but it does not work.

Here is the code:

```
from ebaysdk.shopping import Connection as Shopping

api = Shopping(appid='&',certid='&',devid='&',token='&')
ItemID=&
a = print (api.execute('GetSingleItem',{'ItemID':ItemID,'IncludeSelector':['Title']}))
print(a)
```

The response:

```
<ebaysdk.response.Response object at 0x003A3B10>
None
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify title in your GET request. Ebays Shopping API provides that output field by default. You can check in their documentation [here](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html#detailControls)

It should be noted however, that when using 'InputSelector' it should come before 'ItemId' as the order seems to matter. So your code should look like this.

```
api.execute('GetSingleItem', {'IncludeSelector':outputField,'ItemID':ItemID})
```

Where outputField could be

> Compatibility,
>   Description, Details,   ItemSpecifics,  ShippingCosts,  TextDescription,    Variations

To answer your question simply execute:

```
 response = api.execute('GetSingleItem', {'ItemID':ItemID})
 title = response.dict()['Item']['Title']
 print(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the itemID like this

{
    "ItemID": "000000000000"
}

Comment: I have a working example i will test and post shortly